# Can't find class installed by composer

Tags: php, class, symfony, composer-php

I've downloaded the createsend-php library in my Symfony2 application using:

```
composer require  campaignmonitor/createsend-php
```

It's been downloaded successfuly but when I try to use it..

```
use CS_REST_Lists;
...
public function testNewsletterAction() {

        //... retrieving the keys

        $api = new CS_REST_Lists($listId, $apiKey);
        var_dump($api->get());
        exit;

    }
```

I get the following error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "CS_REST_Lists" from the global namespace in ...
```

In the use statement NetBeans suggested the class name btw. Why is it not working and how can I fix it?

Comment: new \CS_REST_Lists(...).  The use statement is not much help for non-namespaced classes.

Comment: Adding "\" didn't help. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you including the composer autoload file?

Comment: And when you say that netbeans "suggested" the class name, does that mean you don't actually know what the class is called?  Look under vendor or check the docs.

Comment: Suggested = checked and showed the file in which the class is registered

Comment: And yes, the autoload is included since it's Symfony2

Comment: I've discovered that adding $vendorDir . '/campaignmonitor/createsend-php/csrest_lists.php' to autoload_files.php helps but I'm afraid that something will screw up next time I update or install something with composer. Is this a bug in composer or is this just incorrect package configuration?

Comment: Did you check if the bundle is added to **appKernel.php**

Answer (score 1):

According to the libs documentation: https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php you need to require the file yourself

```
require_once 'csrest_lists.php'
```

instead of

```
use \CS_REST_Lists;
```

Although it does look like their composer.json is setup to autoload them so that is strange that the use statement isnt working.

Comment: That's actually a really good point - the classmap should be locating the classes - and testing it, it does for me. So @Tarua must be doing something weird.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but it worked for me...

You don't need to add manually the **classmap.** If you look inside ***vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php*** you can see composer added:

> 'CS_REST_CLASSES' => $vendorDir .'/campaignmonitor/createsend-php/csrest_administrators.php',

Then I tried two things:

- **Instantiate** my class somewhere:

`$cm = new \CS_REST_Lists;`

- **Inject** the class in my **services.yml**:

`my.service:
        class: My\Namespace\MyService
        arguments: [@campaign_monitor]`

```
campaign_monitor:
    class: CS_REST_Lists
    arguments: ['', %campaignmonitor%]
```

The weird part is instantiating worked all the time but **injecting** triggered:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CS_REST_List' not found in /my/code/path/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1779

So I tried to inject a different classmap in my services.yml (i.g **File_Iterator** from phpunit) I assumed that a library like phpunit wouldn't be an issue and it worked. Then I replaced in services.yml **File_Iterator** with **CS_REST_List** and magically it worked...

So... not sure what's going wrong but I think the problem comes from symfony's container not composer. I used symfony 2.5.1